# Exchange PowerShell dropdown issue

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I Am trying to create a drop down box in my form that is set up with two text fields. However when i try to add the dropdown to the form it changes the end values, even though I am not changing the type or answer, it changes the value it returns. The original code I wrote that runs through perfect is:

```
function button ($title,$mailbx, $WF, $TF) {

###################Load Assembly for creating form & button######

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “System.Windows.Forms”)
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName( “Microsoft.VisualBasic”)

#####Define the form size & placement

$form = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Form”;
$form.Width = 750;
$form.Height = 500;
$form.Text = $title;
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen;

##############Define text label1
$textLabel1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel1.Left = 25;
$textLabel1.Top = 15;

$textLabel1.Text = $mailbx;

##############Define text label2

$textLabel2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel2.Left = 25;
$textLabel2.Top = 50;

$textLabel2.Text = $WF;

##############Define text label3

$textLabel3 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Label”;
$textLabel3.Left = 25;
$textLabel3.Top = 85;

$textLabel3.Text = $TF;

############Define text box1 for input
$textBox1 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$textBox1.Left = 150;
$textBox1.Top = 10;
$textBox1.width = 200;

############Define text box2 for input

$textBox2 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$textBox2.Left = 150;
$textBox2.Top = 50;
$textBox2.width = 200;

############Define text box3 for input

$textBox3 = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.TextBox”;
$textBox3.Left = 150;
$textBox3.Top = 90;
$textBox3.width = 200;

#############Define default values for the input boxes
$defaultValue = “”
$textBox1.Text = $defaultValue;
$textBox2.Text = $defaultValue;
$textBox3.Text = $defaultValue;

#############define OK button
$button = New-Object “System.Windows.Forms.Button”;
$button.Left = 360;
$button.Top = 85;
$button.Width = 100;
$button.Text = “Ok”;

############# This is when you have to close the form after getting values
$eventHandler = [System.EventHandler]{
$textBox1.Text;
$textBox2.Text;
$textBox3.Text;
$form.Close();};

$button.Add_Click($eventHandler) ;

#############Add controls to all the above objects defined
$form.Controls.Add($button);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel1);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel2);
$form.Controls.Add($textLabel3);
$form.Controls.Add($textBox1);
$form.Controls.Add($textBox2);
$form.Controls.Add($textBox3);
$ret = $form.ShowDialog();

#################return values

return $textBox1.Text, $textBox2.Text, $textBox3.Text
}

$return= button “Enter Info” “First Name” “Last Name” “Email Address”
$return2 = ($return[0] + " " + $return[1])
$return3 = ($return[0] + "." + $return[1])
$return4 = $return[0] + "." + $return[1] + "$return[2]"


New-Mailbox -Alias $return3 -Name $return2 -FirstName $return[0] -LastName $return[1] -UserPrincipalName $return4  -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@ssw0rd' -AsPlainText -Force) -ResetPasswordOnNextLogon $true
Set-User -Identity $return3 -StreetAddress '1600 Pennsylvania Ave NW' -City 'Washington' -StateOrProvince 'D.C.' -PostalCode '20500' -Phone '202-456-1111' -Fax '202-456-2461'
```

The drop down code I have is

```
########################

# Edit This item to change the DropDown Values

[array]$DropDownArray = "@yahoo.com", "@gmail.com", "@lewisJ.com"

# This Function Returns the Selected Value and Closes the Form

function Return-DropDown {

 $Choice = $DropDown.SelectedItem.ToString()
 }

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")




$DropDown = new-object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDown.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(400,10)
$DropDown.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(130,30)

ForEach ($Item in $DropDownArray) {
 $DropDown.Items.Add($Item)
}

$Form.Controls.Add($DropDown)

$DropDownLabel = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$DropDownLabel.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(10,10) 
$DropDownLabel.size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20) 
$DropDownLabel.Text = "Items"
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownLabel)

$Button = new-object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button.Location = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,50)
$Button.Size = new-object System.Drawing.Size(100,20)
$Button.Text = "OK"
$Button.Add_Click({Return-DropDown})
$form.Controls.Add($Button)
```

I am trying to have it so if I enter the first name as Ben, Last name as Don, and use the drop down feature and select @gmail.com. it will return those values. When I tried to combine the two codes it changed all the values to :

```
System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5 0a3a System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5 0a3a System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089.System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d5 0a3a0
```

Anyone know how to get this drop down correct?

Comment: Welcome back Tyler. So the the return value is just supposed to be '@gmail.com' from the dropdown box nothing else?

Comment: Hey Matt! Good to see you again. There should be 3 values. $return[0] should be the first name. $return[1] should be the last name. And I'm trying to get the 3rd value to be one of the 3 drop down options (@gmail.com, @yahoo.com, @msn.com). However when we input the code for the drop box it returns the values listed above.

Comment: For starters you need to use `[void]` again for the lines in the drop down code that start `[System.Reflection.Assembly]`. Unless that was a copy paste error

Comment: you're right I dont know why I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems once again that you are in need of voiding some return values from the methods in your code. If you look at [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730949.aspx) for a list box (Yes I know we have a drop down) you will see that on top of voiding

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing")
```

You also have to address the `Add` method as well.

```
[void]$DropDown.Items.Add($Item)
```

That should ensure your returns are the ones you want. You might still have an issue with the value from the drop down but this will get you in the right direction.